# Error in visual studio when initialising w SDL

Tags: c++

i am tryanig to do a SDL initialazion class but i get this error on a line thats not even in the file

C2440 : cannot convert from  initialisers list to screen

what have i done wrong this is SDL types i have included SDL and it works fine so no error there the error seems to be in the constructor

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Screen.h"

using namespace std;

Screen::Screen()
    : m_window(NULL)
    , m_renderer(NULL)
    , m_texture(NULL)
    , m_buffer(NULL)
{
}

bool Screen::Init()
{
    if ((SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    m_window = SDL_CreateWindow("Particle Simulation", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    if (m_window == NULL) {
        SDL_Quit();
        return 2;
    }

    m_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    m_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(m_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    if (m_renderer == NULL) {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 3;
    }
    if (m_texture == NULL) {
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
        SDL_Quit();

        return 4;
    }

    m_buffer = new Uint32[SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT];

    memset(m_buffer, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT * sizeof(Uint32));

    m_buffer[30000] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT; i++) {
        m_buffer[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
    SDL_UpdateTexture(m_texture, NULL, m_buffer, SCREEN_WIDTH * sizeof(Uint32));
    SDL_RenderClear(m_renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(m_renderer, m_texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(m_renderer);
    return true;
}
bool Screen::processEvents()
{
    return false;
}
void Screen::close()
{
    delete[] m_buffer;
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_renderer);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(m_texture);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and copy the full exact text of the error message from the Output tab. Also indicate what line# the error occurs on.

Comment: its on no line it says line 86 it doesnt exist